# adding string with multiple spaces to a text file

Tags: c++

i have this code below where i am doing a add expense to a text file but when i run the code the input of the file becomes

```
:200:25jan
```

i use the getline(cin, expense); to get the entire string on line but it ended up blank , need some help please

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void addExpense(string& expense, double& amount, string& date){ 
cout << "Type of Expense: " << endl;
getline(cin, expense);
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(100, '\n');
cout << "Amount: " << endl;
cin >> amount;
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(100, '\n');
cout << "Transaction Date: " << endl;
getline (cin, date);
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(100, '\n');
}

int main() {
char choice;
bool expenseOn = true;
while (expenseOn != false){
 cout << "a) Add Expense\n";   
 cout << "b) Remove Expense\n";
 cout << "c) Edit Cash Flow item for Expense or Income\n";
 cout << "d) Net Cash Flow Summary Report\n";
 cout << "e) Quit\n";
 cout << "\n";
 cout << "Please Enter a Choice:\n";

 cin.clear ();
 cin >> choice;

 string date = "", expense = "", texpense = "";
 ofstream outfile;
 double amount = 0.0;

switch (choice){
    case 'a':
        cout << "Add Expense.\n";
        //char fileName[20];
        /*cout << "Enter filename.." << endl;
        cin >> fileName;*/ 
        outfile.open ("Expense.txt");
        if (!outfile)
        {
        cout << "File Storing Failed" << endl;
        exit(-1);
        }
        addExpense(expense, amount, date);
        outfile << expense << ":" << amount << ":" << date;
        break;
     }
```

Comment: What result did you expect/desire?

Comment: Your code fragment does not show if you close or flush the outfile later on. Maybe that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible answer for this question

```
string expense = "", date = "", type = "";
double amount = 0.0;
ofstream outfile; 
outfile.open ("Expense.txt", std::ios_base::app);
if (!outfile)
{
cout << "File open fail" << endl;
exit(-1);
}
cout << "Please Enter Expense: ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, expense);
cin.clear();
cout << "Amount: " << endl;
cin >> amount;      
cin.clear();
cout << "Transaction Date: " << endl;
cin.ignore(100,'\n');
getline (cin, date);
outfile << expense << ":" << amount << ":" << date << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing `ignore` - you should use that when and only when you really need to skip to the next line.
When you use `getline` you're extracting an entire line, including the newline, from the stream.
When you use `>>`, newlines are left in the stream to be read later.

This is what happens:

```
void addExpense(string& expense, double& amount, string& date){ 
    cout << "Type of Expense: " << endl;
    getline(cin, expense);   // Read the newline that was left after reading 'choice'
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');   // Read the line containing the type of expense 
    cout << "Amount: " << endl;
    cin >> amount;           // Read the amount
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');   // Read to the end of line
    cout << "Transaction Date: " << endl;
    getline (cin, date);     // Read the line containing the date
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');   // Read to the end of line
}
```

(You may have noticed that you need to press Enter twice after the date in order to continue. The second one is what the final `ignore` is waiting for.)

Remove the `ignore`s after the `getline`s, and add one after `cin >> choice`.